# Overriding "Important" to make a div hidden

Tags: html, css

```
left: auto !important; 
top: -55px !important; 
right: 0px !important; 
bottom: auto !important; 
display: block !important; 
visibility: visible !important; 
position: absolute;
```

This is the css styles of div that I need to have hidden. I have tried many different things. I cannot change the code, but I can add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
opacity: 0 !important;
height: 0 !important;
width: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Thanks! Opacity worked. It didn't collapse the space, but it hid it. Good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
display: none !important;
```